# String Operation Java to search a subString sequence

Tags: java, string, collections

We have a string declared as follows:
String strString="This is a test statement to find a sub sequence of string";

There doesn't seem to be a method in String class that will search a sub sequence, like:
Given 
String strString2="test ststement to find";

Here strString2 is a sub sequence of strString, Is there a way to find without character compare?

Comment: Take a look for yourself: [String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition to check existence of strString2 in strString is:

```
strString.indexOf(strString2) >= 0
```

or

```
strString.contains(strString2)
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are looking for [`String#indexOf(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28java.lang.String%29).  That will also give you the location in the string if it's found.

Answer (score 2):

[String.contains(CharSequence s)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains%28java.lang.CharSequence%29)

> Returns true if and only if this string contains the specified
>   sequence of char values.

You can do something like this.

```
String strString="This is a test statement to find a sub sequence of string";
strString2="test ststement to find";
if(strString.contains(strString2)){
    //Do something. 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
string1.contains(string2);`
```

Please note that it will throw a `NullPointerException` if `string2` is `null`. You have to make sure that the `string2` is not null before trying the comparison; the other situations should handle as you would expect. You can also use the `toLowerCase()` method along with `contains()` method if you would like to ignore case.

```
string1.toLowerCase().contains(string2.toLowerCase())
```

Also for older versions, you could use `indexOf()` method. If `string2` is not in `string1`, `indexOf` will give you `-1`. Here also you must ensure beforehand that both Strings are not `null` though to avoid a `NullPointerException`.